# PrimeUI Column text formatting

Tags: jquery, prime-ui

I am using primeUI to generate datatable. I want to format column text. below is my code to load primeUI datatable.

```
$('#tbl').puidatatable({
        caption: 'Local Datasource',
        columns: [
            {field: 'legendText', headerText: 'Text'},
            {field: 'legendPercentage', headerText: '%age'},
            {field: 'legendValue', headerText: 'value'}
        ],
        datasource: responseData
    });
```

i want to format column text. Can anyone help me in this? i want value to be currency formatted. and %age column in two decimal format like this.

### text| %age |value|

abc | 30.00 |123,3|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to it's document

http://www.primefaces.org/primeui/#datatable

> content: A function that takes row data and expects a string or a jQuery object to customize the cell.

it seems easy,

```
columns: [
{ field: 'vin', 
  content: function(rowData) { 
            console.log(rowData);
//format column data here, then return the formatted value
            return rowData.vin;
            },
  headerText: 'Vin'
},

{field: 'brand', headerText: 'Brand'},
{field: 'year', headerText: 'Year'},
{field: 'color', headerText: 'Color'}
]
```